# trying to Integrate alexa with dialogflow webhook(cloud function)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to integrate alexa with dialogflow and trying to use external api.
For static agent request and response it is working fine but when response is coming from external api in Dialogflow then alexa is not responding anything.

To get the speech from Dialogflow I am using, response.result.fulfillment.speech in lambda function, but same is not working for webhook(cloud function).
Please help me on this.

Comment: I implemented this using https://github.com/Gnzlt/AlexaApiAiBridge,but not working for webhook response.

Comment: it is working with https://github.com/Gnzlt/AlexaApiAiBridge this code not with webhook response.